# Nginx error 403 on file upload - passing multipart/form-data to the proxy/server

Tags: nginx, upload

I have a very simple Nginx server that forwards traffic from subdomain to my http server on port 8000 like so :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name *.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

My http server then takes care of everything by reading the hostame etc and it's working fine for any basic api/json requests.

Now i'm trying to send a file to my server but get a 403 error from nginx on sending the file / multipart form data.

From reading the [doc](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) i'm a bit confused as " upload_pass_args " seems to require a dedicated route configured in the conf file and that's not something i want at all. I just need the multipart / form data passed to my server's router to be handled ( the http server on :8000 )

I've also try to include `sendfile on;` in both my server{} or inside location{} but to no success.

Comment: i think  proxy_request_buffering  off; might have just helped

Comment: Why complicate things by putting one reverse proxy in front of another?

Comment: i'm no where near a pro at this. I'm just trying to redirect localhost:9000 to one domain  and all the subdomains to another server thats why i'm using the reverse proxy. do you mean i should write it as 2 separate server{} and not proxy{} ?

Comment: No, I meant not using Nginx at all, but the webserver you've currently got running on localhost:8000.  Have it listening on port 80 too, and problem solved.

Comment: ah yeah but there's 2 app on the same machine running on different local ports but both listening on 80  ( on serving domain.com and the one from the question running sudbomains.domain.com )

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_request_buffering off;` will fix the issue.

From reading [this](https://serverfault.com/a/741612/578808) answer i suspect a proper configuration of the buffer would be the way to go when i've tried/done that i'll try to update this answer.