# Optimizing nginx client_body_buffer_size for web app accepting file uploads

Tags: nginx, optimization

When configuring nginx, what considerations affect `client_body_buffer_size`?

I've set it to `10m` for a website where users upload photos and image-memes (kind of like [9gag](https://9gag.com/)). Note that `client_max_body_size` is set to `10m` as well. Overall, my reasoning is that the webserver should accept POST requests with images as big as 10MB (website policy) - and thus both these directives ought to be `10m`.

Is this reasoning correct?

Can someone shed light on the factors affecting what values to set for `client_body_buffer_size`, and typical values of `client_body_buffer_size` (for the sort of web application I described)?

In case it matters, I utilize nginx as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/client_body_buffer_size) states what `client_body_buffer_size` does:

> Sets buffer size for reading client request body. In case the request body is larger than the buffer, the whole body or only its part is written to a temporary file. By default, buffer size is equal to two memory pages. This is 8K on x86, other 32-bit platforms, and x86-64. It is usually 16K on other 64-bit platforms.

This memory is in use only while a request is being uploaded; once it is passed on to the backend, the memory is freed again. If a request is larger than this value, it will go to a temporary file and [a warning will appear](https://serverfault.com/q/511789/126632) in the error log.

This means that you must have enough RAM to store any simultaneous uploads, or your server will begin swapping.

The performance impact of this is probably not that great, unless you are severely memory constrained and getting lots of uploads at the same time.

Comment: So would that mean `client_body_buffer_size` is dictated by the upper limit of the upload file sizes my application would accept?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have a buffer size larger than the upload size you can accept. You could configure it, but it would not have any effect.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. What confuses me is that most examples I see cite `client_body_buffer_size` size at `10k`, whereas `client_max_body_size` is set to `8m`. What kind of scenarios are those? Shouldn't buffer size *always* be as big as body size?

Comment: @HassanBaig The typical request body is a form submission of perhaps a few hundred bytes at most. Image uploading is not a common operation for most web sites. If you only get three or four uploads per day it doesn't matter much whether it's going to RAM or a temporary file.